# How 'git rebase' and 'git pull' work together?

Tags: git

I understand that 'git rebase' abandons some of the commits. So if a developer does so ,and push the changes to a remote repo then does it mean that those  commits would also be removed from remote repo.

And when another developer does 'git pull', would those commits be removed from his/her local repo too?

Comment: The commits abandoned are first *copied* to new (presumably better) commits. So the end result is (a bit oversimplified) that you have the same number of commits, all of which do the same thing as before, but with different hash IDs, starting from a different starting-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase does not abandon some of the commits, not unless you do an interactive rebase and explicitly delete certain commits.  Rather, doing a `git pull` with a rebase strategy does the opposite; it preserves all commits in your local branch while updating with changes from the remote branch.

A picture is worth a thousand words here.  Following is a diagram showing what a local branch would look like before and after a git pull via rebase.

```
remote: ... A -- B -- C
             \
local:        D -- E
```

Intially, the most recent ancestor is `A`, and since that point your local and remote branch have *diverged* by 2 commits each.  If you were to run `git status`, Git would tell you that your branch is 2 commits behind and 2 ahead of its remote counterpart.  Now do a pull via rebase:

```
git pull --rebase origin your_branch
```

After the pull, the diagram looks like this:

```
remote: ... A -- B -- C
                       \
local:                  D' -- E'
```

Note that the top two commits on your local branch are still `D` and `E`, in that order.  But now your work sits on top of the remote version of the branch.  This is why the command is called "rebasing," because it gives your branch a new base when pulling.

Doing a pull via rebase stands in juxtaposition to doing a normal `git pull` via a merge.  Had you merged the remote branch into your local branch, you would end up with this:

```
remote: ... A -- B -- C
             \         \
local:        D -- E -- M
```

Now the remote commits `B` and `C` do not appear directly in the history of your local branch.  Instead, you are left with a merge commit (`M` in the above diagram).  In other words, pulling via merge tends to consololidate commits, while rebasing tends to preseve history.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question here:

When we do 'git pull --rebase', then what is the order of operations?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by order of operations, but a rebase pull basically happens in 3 steps: 1) rewind your local branch to the most recent common ancestor, 2) apply the commits from the _remote_, and finally 3) reapply your local commits since the common ancestor.  My answer tries to show these steps.

Comment: @Mandroid if you're not concerned about the order of the commits you could do a git fetch then rebase onto your local branch

Comment: If I do git fetch and then rebase, I think we still get same order of commits as shown in the figure by @TimBiegeleisen. Am I right?

Comment: So what I understand by 'git pull --rebase' is that it does 'git fetch' and then do 'git rebase'. On the other hand a plain 'git pull' would also first do 'git fetch' and then 'git merge'. Hence the difference.

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin branch` is the same as `git fetch origin` followed by `git rebase origin/branch`.

Comment: @Mandroid I think you probably understand it a bit off, if you do `git pull --rebase`, you would run into some merge conflict troubles if you're not lucky enough to have totally isolated changes from your collaborator.

Comment: @Mandroid and the reason of that is cause someone else did a rebase on a shared branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Would you mind elaborating a bit more on ` rebasing tends to preseve history.`, this could be really confusing though.

Comment: Regarding this, i think its 'merge' which tends to preserve history.
Have a look at 'Rebase vs. Merge' at:https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: Ya, merge is always safer at the cost of a less cleaner(linear) history. Rebase generally will overwrite history, not only `rebase --interactive` but also `rebase --onto <SHA>` every later commits after SHA gets changed. Think it as cherry-pick commits one-by-one.

Comment: Though this explains `git pull --rebase` fairly well, i don't quite get what's related to your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer short, `git rebase` (by someone else) followed by `git pull` (by you) probably wasn't something you wanna do, generally consider don't rebase on a shared branch unless you're sure what you're doing.

Assume the branch you're working on isn't a master (never rebase on master), it's still a **shared** branch. Typically rebase **rewrites** history/SHA of commits, if someone rewrites the history, a **force** push is required, while it's common to force push to private branch(say your own), it's not the case for public branch.

If you wanna stick with rebase strategy on a shared branch, a common strategy is using `git pull --rebase` or `git rebase origin/<local_branch> # instead of origin/master`, this way rebase doesn't rewrite history anymore, thus safe to use, though it feels a bit off what it's designed for.

Comment: Some Git workflows which rely on rebase (e.g. certain open source projects follow this) do not necessitate force pushing.  Rather, everyone simply rebases and afterwards can directly push onto the remote branch.

Comment: I thought by default it's required since you're changing history (at risk), you mean turning off *force* option through git config?

Comment: Rebasing a local feature branch on its remote counterpart does not require doing a force push.  Rather, the commits on top of the local branch after the rebase can just fast forward the remote.  The problem which you have highlighted would happen if we rebased a feature on master.  Then we'd have to force push feature.